# Solving second order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I faced a problem while solving a second order differential equation. Please help me with this problem.
Solve $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+ux=0,u>0$ given that $x=a$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$, when $t=\frac{π}{2\sqrt{u}}$ .

Thanks,

Comment: are you sure you wrote the equation right?

Comment: where does $t $ involve.

Comment: Is u constant? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This is the question what i got in my book.So no idea on it.

Comment: Why do I suspect that the question is in fact $\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} + uy = 0$ with the other conditions that follow.

Comment: What exactly was the problem you faced when solving the differential equation?

Comment: I could't get correct answer for this problem.

Comment: And what is the presumed correct answer to the problem?

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake someone had edited my question ,presumed answer is x=asin√u t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y''=-ux $$
$$y'=-u\frac {x^2}{2}+C_1$$
$$y=-u\frac {x^3}{6}+C_1x+C_2$$

with initial conditions
$$x=\frac {\pi}{2\sqrt {u}}\implies y'=0$$
$$\implies C_1=\pi^2/8$$

Finish using the other condition and find $C_2$.

Comment: But $y''= ux$ was NOT the problem posted!

Comment: @user247327, look at the edit history. The OP changed the equation after the fact

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+ \mu x= 0$ is a fairly standard differential equation *with constant coefficients*.  Its characteristic equation is $r^2+ \mu= 0$ which, assuming $\mu$ is positive has roots $i\sqrt{\mu}$ and $-i\sqrt{\mu}$.

The general solution to the given differential equation is $x(t)= A cos(\sqrt{\mu t})+ B sin(\sqrt{\mu}t)$. $x'(t)= -A\sqrt{\mu} sin(\sqrt{\mu}t)+ B\sqrt{\mu} cos(\sqrt{\mu}t)$.

When $t= \frac{\pi}{2\mu}$, $x'(t)= -A\sqrt{\mu} sin(\frac{\pi}{2})+ B\sqrt{\mu} cos(\frac{\pi}{2})= -A= 0$.

and $x(t)= B sin(\frac{\pi}{2})= B= a$.

The solution to this initial value problem is $x(t)= a sin(\sqrt{\mu} t)$.